# So Trivial: Write "" in Java

Tags: java, string, syntax

**This is the most trivial question but I cannot figure out how to solve this.**

In a String I want to relace all the occurences of this string " with this ""

My problem is that the compiler wont allow me to write """" or '""' (hope this makes sense).

So my code is:

```
s = s.replace('"', '""'); // so the 2nd parameter of the method is causing an error
```

I hope this makes sense :P

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: (using replace instead of replaceAll per suggestion)

```
s = s.replace("\"", "\"\"");
```

Comment: Too complicated - why to use regex here? `s = s.replace("\"", "\"\"");` is surely much faster.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflowException's answer is correct. you need to escape quotes with a blackslash

keep in mind that (unlike some other languages) single quotes are for single characters 
and double quotes are for strings of 0 or more characters

e.g.

```
'a'   'b'   '1'   '\"' 
""   "a"   "this is a string"
```